# Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section. Can't add row for TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Error Message -

Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 2.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (8) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (8), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Trying to add a Custom UITableViewCell when tapped at a specific section and row. The types are enums that I define in cellForRowAtIndexPath -

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

BucketListCellType type = [[[self.presentedCells objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  intValue];

  if (type == mainPhotoCellWithAddToBucketList) {

    BucketListShellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return cell;
}

else if (type == mainPhotoCell) {

    BucketListShellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return cell;
}
else if (type == CreateNewBucketListCell) {
    CreateNewBucketListTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Create" forIndexPath:indexPath];
//        self.collectionView.alpha = 0;
    return cell;

}

else if (type == CategoryCell) {

    BucketListCategoryTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Category" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    BucketListCategory *category = [self.bucketListCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1];
    cell.bucketListNameLabel.text = category.name;

    return cell;

}

else if (type == CategoryPhotosCell) {
    BucketListCategoryPhotosTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CategoryPhotos"];
    return cell;

}
return nil
}
```

Here is the code for when you tap on a cell -

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

BucketListCellType type = [[[self.presentedCells objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue];


if (type == CreateNewBucketListCell) {


    UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                  alertControllerWithTitle:@"New Bucket List"
                                  message:@"Create a new Bucket List"
                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                   //Do Some action here

                                                   [APIManager createBucketListCategory:alert.textFields.firstObject.text completionHandler:^(RequestStatus status) {

                                                   }];
                                               }];
    UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                       [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                   }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    [alert addAction:cancel];

    [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"I want to..";
    }];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else if (type == CategoryCell) {


    [self expandCategoryCell];

}

}
```

Here is the next method

```
-(void)expandCategoryCell {
NSMutableArray *preCells = [NSMutableArray new];

// First Section - Suggested Bucket List Images

NSMutableArray *suggestedBucketListImages = [NSMutableArray new];

[suggestedBucketListImages addObject:@(mainPhotoCellWithAddToBucketList)];
[suggestedBucketListImages addObject:@(mainPhotoCellWithAddToBucketList)];

[preCells addObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:suggestedBucketListImages]];

// Second Section - Top Bucket List Images

NSMutableArray *topBucketListImages = [NSMutableArray new];

[topBucketListImages addObject:@(mainPhotoCell)];

[preCells addObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:topBucketListImages]];

// Third Section - My Bucket List Images

NSMutableArray *myBucketListCategories = [NSMutableArray new];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
[myBucketListCategories addObject:@(CreateNewBucketListCell)];

for (int i = 0; i < [self.bucketListCategories count]; i++) {

    [myBucketListCategories addObject:@(CategoryCell)];
    if (i == indexPath.row) {

        [myBucketListCategories addObject:@(CategoryPhotosCell)];

    }


}

[preCells addObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:myBucketListCategories]];


NSMutableArray *unorganizedBucketListImages = [NSMutableArray new];

[unorganizedBucketListImages addObject:@(mainPhotoCell)];
[preCells addObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:unorganizedBucketListImages]];

[self.tableView beginUpdates];

self.presentedCells = preCells;
NSArray *indexPaths = @[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(indexPath.row + 1) inSection:indexPath.section]];

[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

[self.tableView endUpdates];



}
```

I am not getting any error messages. It just stops working at `[self.tableView endUpdates]`. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Disable breakpoints and run the app. You should see a nice big error message about some sort of mismatch in the number of rows/sections added,deleted,updated.

Comment: Thanks, I added it

Comment: Why are the arrays like `myBucketListCategories` local to the `expandCategoryCell` method?  Don't they hold the model data and therefore need to be accessible from the datasource (delegate) methods?

Comment: It's just a temporary Array to add to the preCells array. The array that hold the model and data for that is in self.BucketListCategories and is global. If you see I'm setting the sections and at the end just sending the pointer to self.presentedCells.

Comment: Well there is too much to see the actual problem but basically your data model and tableview row/section count are out-of-sync.  That's what the exception message means.  I don't see the purpose of the temporary arrays when you can just manipulate the data model arrays directly.